# Random Object reference

Tags: c#

Yes, I searched this situation, but couldn't really relate the others to this... ( Don't bash me please...)

```
public Random Randomizer; 

string[] Monsters = { "Rat", "Giant Rat", "Skeleton", "Infected" };

public string DisplayKilled() 
{
    if (PlayerOne.Level <= 5) 
    {
        string randomMonster = Monsters[Randomizer.Next(1,2)]; // <= problemo
```

Error I'm getting at "string randomMonster = Monsters[Randomizer.Next(1,2)];" 
 : ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*** What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can initialize your variable. Currently, you're never setting it to a value. It's *declared* here:

```
public Random Randomizer;
```

... but you never give it a value, so it will have the default value of `null`, which causes an exception to be thrown when you dereference it. It's worth understanding that this has *nothing* to do with the fact that it's about randomness... the same would occur with *any* reference type variable, e.g. a `string` or a `Stream`.

You *could* just use:

```
private readonly Random randomizer = new Random();
```

... but there are other drawbacks with that. (Note that I've made it private and readonly - you should avoid public fields almost everywhere, and make it readonly unless you really want the value to vary over the lifetime of the object.)

In terms of the drawbacks, there are two to worry about:

- If you create multiple instances of `Random` with the parameterless constructor in a very short space of time, many of them may share the same seed, which means they'll produce the same random numbers.
- `Random` isn't thread-safe - if you use a single instance from multiple threads without any locking, you can easily get into a state where it just returns 0 every time.

The two of these are particularly nasty together... if it weren't for the thread-safety aspect, it would be fairly reasonable to just declare a single static field and use the same instance for everything. But that doesn't work if you've got multiple threads involved. Likewise if the shared seed weren't a problem, it would be fine to just create one every time you needed one.

I have a [page on randomness in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) which goes into more details around this and suggests some workarounds.

Comment: Oh, Derp user2129296 = new Derp();

Comment: My guess is that he creates more than one instance (shared seed) but uses only a single thread, and in that case you're kind of saying he should make `randomizer` static, as in `private static readonly Random randomizer = new Random();`. I also think he should make it static. (Only if it's multi-threaded, and if each thread has its own instances that are not used by the other threads, and if multiple instances are not created with short time, _then_ it would be better to keep the field non-static.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I think making it static is a risky business - it's all too easy to be using a single thread now, but later use multiple threads and forget that you've got this time-bomb waiting...

Answer (score 1):

```
public Random Randomizer = new Random();
```